# React Redux - Can't repalce the list via dispatch action

Tags: reactjs, redux

I would like to dispatch the action then replace the whole tab(List) in the State with the tabs2 (List), But now it keep appending the new tab into the tab(List), anyone can help?

```
  function reducreForTabs(state = initialState4, action) {
          if (typeof state === 'undefined') {
            return 0
          }
    
          switch(action.type) {
              case 'GET_DETAIL': {
                  
                  var tabs2 = [{ 'id': 'newList' }];
                         
                  return {...state,
                        tabs: state.tabs.concat(tab2)
                      };
    
              }
              default :{
                  return state
              }
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is concat in javascript: array1.concat(array2, array3, ..., arrayX)

```
function reducreForTabs(state = initialState4, action) {
          if (typeof state === 'undefined') {
            return 0
          }

          switch(action.type) {
              case 'GET_DETAIL': {

                  var tabs2 = [{ 'id': 'newList' }];

                  return {...state,
                        tabs: state.tabs.concat(tab2)
                      };

              }
              default :{
                  return state
              }
          }
        }
```